# Not able to perform nslookup to Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I am trying to do a `nslookup` of the Service but it always gives `** server can't find kubernetes: NXDOMAIN` error.

I have already checked all the answers which suggest using a busybox image but that too is not working. Below are screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Anyone has any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Turing85, with all due respect, maybe you don't understand Kubernetes, but this is directly related to programming and coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `busybox` image solution is still patchy, for some it works and for some it doesn't. Try creating a pod as per below spec from [kubernetes.io](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/main/content/en/examples/admin/dns/dnsutils.yaml):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dnsutils
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: dnsutils
    image: registry.k8s.io/e2e-test-images/jessie-dnsutils:1.3
    command:
      - sleep
      - "infinity"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
```

And then use this command - `kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- nslookup <<Service_Name>>`.